# Want two instances (Windows) of Notepad++

Tags: notepad++, multiple-instances

I am not a programmer, just a user who finds Notepad++ very useful.

I want to open Notepad++ twice for separate projects. Each would open with different shortcut (icons). I've read about opening separate instances of Notepad++ using `-multiInst` and/or `-nosession` and have not figured this out. I either open the original instance or a blank instance (with no obvious way to open the first, much less the second).

Someone had suggested loading Notepad++ twice, but all that happens is an over-write. I tried creating a sub-directory in Notepad++ with the same results as above.

I am using Windows XP and Notepad++ 5.9.6.2

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: My recommendation if you want to have two notepad++s open at the same time: Open two windows inside of one notepad++ and drag one of the those windows by clicking the tap (what separates the two files) and drag it outside of your notepad++ application.  This will open two windows of Notepad++

Comment: I tried both of these with basically the same results. Where is the second instance/window?

My current shortcut icon is:

   Target: "C:\Program Files\Notepad++\notepad++.exe" with or without various combinations of  -multiInst -nosession
   Start In: "C:\Program Files\Notepad++\localization"

It would seem to me that my shortcut icon should point to my original set of .txt files and 
that a second shortcut should point to my new set of .txt files, but this does not seem
to be the case. At least not as far I can determine. (If I'm wrong, please reveal behind
which curtain the Wiz is.

Comment: NB For some reason Zero Stack's suggestion doesn't work if you drag a new tab, even if you type text first. But save as a temp file and it works.

Comment: If you're looking for an easy solution, IMHO ZeroStacks advice is surpassed by the answer on the existing (duplicate) question

Answer (score 42):

I tested some options from the [Notepad++ wiki](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/notepad-plus/index.php?title=Multiple_Instances), and this one worked for me while others didn't.

I know you already mentioned *-multiInst*. But maybe you are doing something wrong? I just added a detailed description:

1. Create a new shortcut to your notepad++.exe
2. Go to Properties of the shortcut (right-click on it)
3. Append *-multiInst* to the target line. It should look like this
   [image]

   <sup>Notepad++ v6.2.3.</sup>

---

Since [Notepad++ v6.4.3](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/news/notepad-6.4.3-release.html) a new option was added which enables multi instances:

[image]

Comment: Except it would make a difference because your using a totaly different version `v5` vs `v6`

Comment: I tested his [version 5.9.6.2](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/download/v5.9.6.2.html) and its working with *-multiInst*.

Comment: I tried both of these with basically the same results. Where is the second instance/window. My current shortcut icon is Target: "C:\Program Files\Notepad++\notepad++.exe" -multiInst

Start In: "C:\Program Files\Notepad++\localization"

Comment: @David I can't tell you what went wrong on your system. The  -multiInst method is a widely accepted method. But I have searched once more and [stumbled up this](http://superuser.com/questions/202399/how-to-make-notepad-open-each-file-in-new-window). please try the method with that empty file called *asNotepad.xml*

Comment: I tried both of these with basically the same results. Where is the second instance/window?

My current shortcut icon is:

   Target: "C:\Program Files\Notepad++\notepad++.exe" with or without various combinations of  -multiInst -nosession
   Start In: "C:\Program Files\Notepad++\localization"

It would seem to me that my shortcut icon should point to my original set of .txt files and 
that a second shortcut should point to my new set of .txt files, but this does not seem
to be the case. At least not as far I can determine. (If I'm wrong, please reveal behind
which curtain the Wiz is.

Comment: Thank you nixda! The posting by Matt Brunell, plus a little insight of my own answered the question. While I have only suspicions how my original instance of Notepadd++ works, I am reasonably sure I can open more instances if necessary.

Comment: n.b. When I tried this, I *thought* that I wasn't getting a second instance but was, in fact, stacking up new Notepad++ windows, all with the same session being opened. Adding -multiInst -nosession remedied that, giving me a nice clean second window.

Comment: Wanted to add that in Windows 10, after you've enabled the multi-inst, you can right click the notepad++ icon in the taskbar and hit notepad++ to open new window. Took me a second to figure it out, so wanted to share.

Answer (score 14):

In version 6.6.9 just right-click on the file tab and choose *open in new instance*.

Comment: Beware that this appears to only work with "clean buffers", i.e. a file that is unmodified since last save. If I just "randomly paste some stuff", I can't *move to new instance*. (This was mentioned over on [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13252968/122764). Maybe this behaviour is the source of the downvote?)

Comment: Another gotcha is it doesn't work on Ctrl+N new files (not until they have been saved at least). The option is grayed out. Otherwise this is the correct answer for me.